# How to find the following series sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am looking at $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2 \log k}$. I know that it converges as $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2 \log k}\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges. Thanks and appreciate a hint!

Comment: Have you considered developing an asymptotic approximation using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula?

Comment: Interesting, did not occur to me. Let me try that, the best I could go so far was upper bound the summation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no "closed form", but we can do this.

You can write it as $$S(2) - \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^2 \log k}$$ where
$$S(s) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s \log k} $$

Now $$ S'(s) = - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s} = 1 - \zeta(s)$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function, so $S(s)$ is an antiderivative of $1 - \zeta(s)$.  In fact, since $S(s) \to 0$ as $s \to \infty$, we get

$$ S(2) = \int_2^\infty (\zeta(s)-1)\; ds $$

Comment: Thanks, did not think in terms of extrapolating the sum to zeta function form and yes the best we can do is approximate or upper bound the sum I think.